# How do I add a new column to an existing DataTable and fill it with a default value?

Tags: powershell, datatable

Suppose I have a Datatable in Powershell that looks like this:

```
ID    Value
-----------
1     Foo
2     Bar
```

And I wanted to add a `Status` column with the default value of "Normal". I create the new column with:

```
$MyDataTable.Columns.Add("Status", [String]) | Out-Null
$MyDataTable.Columns["Status"].DefaultValue = "Normal"

$MyDataTable | Format-Table
```

The new column is created but the default value is not applied.

```
ID    Value    Status
---------------------
1     Foo
2     Bar
```

Given it is an existing DataTable, how do I fill the new column with its default value?

Comment: As from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue). The `DefaultValue` _Gets or sets the default value for the column when you are creating **new rows**._ Since you are not adding new rows, the new column does not get this default values and you will have to insert that on all existing rows yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DefaultValue` on the column *before* adding it to the table:

```
# Define column with default value
$StatusColumn = [System.Data.DataColumn]::new('Status', [string])
$StatusColumn.DefaultValue = 'Normal'

# Add column definition to table
$MyDataTable.Columns.Add($StatusColumn)
```